Troubleshooting Error: Loading 60k Records into Dynamics 365 Transaction Entity using KingswaySoft
Using Kingsway Soft to load 60k records into Transaction entity in CE but getting this error even when I am trying to load first 200 records: Any idea how to resolve this?
[Dynamics CRM Destination [2]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.CrmServiceException: CRM service call returned an error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (Error Type / Reason: BadRequest, Detailed Message: {"error":{"code":"0x80040265","message":"Exception: Cannot use this database resource because another request is currently using the resource. This error indicates that there may be a high number of requests attempting to use the same resource, or the request which is currently using the resource is doing a large amount of work. Database resource and error details:, mode:Update - stored procedure sp_getapplock returned error code -3. The lock request was chosen as a deadlock victim. This can occur when there are multiple update requests on the same record. Please retry the request.."}}) (SSIS Integration Toolkit for Microsoft Dynamics 365, v23.2.1.29601 - DtsDebugHost, v15.0.2000.132)KingswaySoft.IntegrationToolkit.DynamicsCrm.WebAPI.WebApiServiceException

The issue may be related to setting the combination of batch size (the number of records processed in a single call) and thread count (the number of calls being processed in parallel) to be larger than the service allows, resulting in the message ‘high number of requests attempting to use the same resource’. As a temporary test, could you please set the batch size to a lower value and the thread count to 1; if successful, you may incrementally increase these settings as required. If you still receive the same error with a thread count of 1 and a lower batch size, please reach out to our support team at www.kingswaysoft.com/about-us/contact-us so we can have a closer look at this case.
